# Where to document database schema in arc42?

Tags: architecture, arc42

I want to document a software project using the arc42 template. Where can I document the database schema? Is it a building block, so it has to be part of chapter 5 (Building Block View)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explain it in chapter 8 (concepts), section "Persistence":

There you both clarify your

- persistence strategy and implementation approach, and
- data model and mapping to internal objects/building-blocks/domain-entities or whatever you use.

I suggest to keep chapter 4 (solution strategy) as brief as possible - better include links to later chapters.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that it belongs to

1. Chapter 4 (Solution strategy) where you describe why you chose a DB to solve your problem and
2. Chapter 9 (Architecture Decisions) documenting how you arrived at that specific DB schema.

So it does not explicitly belong to the building block view.